# How will Mana be implemented into the tangle?

Tags: iota-network

I have searched for detailed information about Mana on the IOTA Documentation site but I haven't found anything. Is there any other resource about Mana that I am missing?

Comment: How about this: https://blog.iota.org/explaining-mana-in-iota-6f636690b916/

Comment: Thanks. I already read this blogpost. I was looking for a more detailed document. Is there a paper about it?